# Laravel 5.6 storage link already exists but i am getting 404 error when trying to get a file from the public folder

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I've created a symlink using the command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then I've created a file in `storage/app/public`.  Following the documentation, I could get the link to this file with:

```
asset('storage/file.txt')
```

Which returns in the html code:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/psps.txt
```

But I am getting 404 error.  Any help?

Comment: can you try with `asset('file.txt')` ?

Comment: same thing , the first one i used seems to be correct because it's on official documentation

Comment: Does the webserver have read permissions to that file?

Comment: What operational system are you using? Because if you are using Windows, that could be windows permission problem. If you're using linux check the folder owner.

Comment: I am assuming it is just a typo here - `file.txt` !== `psps.txt`? Is Laravel installed correctly, specifically did you [set up directory permissions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#configuration)?  What are the permissions on your newly created `file|psps.txt`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to your project's `public` folder, and delete the `storage` folder, if it exists.
Then run this command line:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the project root and copy and paste this two command

```
rm -rf public/storage
php artisan storage:link
```